# Como actualizar la hora en dos inputs distintos con la fecha en ajax con js y pdo

Tags: ajax, pdo, fullcalendar

Tengo el siguiente formulario para actualizar la hora con hora con ajax y la fecha en distintos inputs, pero este no me actualiza ni a la de tres en cambio si me actualiza los demás inputs como el titulo, el color, y la descripción, no se como aplicarlo para que le afecte también a la hora y se lo paso a todo por POST en la consulta ajax.

Aquí el código del formulario.
***Tablas***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Formulario editar***

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEditar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editarEvento.php">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap my-2 personalizado">
                                    <span class="input-group-text-desplegable" id="addon-wrapping">
                                        <i class="fa fa-mobile iconos-editar-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <select name="id_usuarios" class="col-sm-6 custom-control-desplegable">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Asignar Usuario </option>
                                        <?php
                                        $query_usuarios = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
                                        $usuarios = $query_usuarios->fetchAll();

                                        foreach ($usuarios as $fila_usuarios) {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $fila_usuarios["id_usuarios"] ?>" <?php {
                                                                                                        echo ' selected="selected"';
                                                                                                    } ?>>
                                                <?= $fila_usuarios["nombre"] ?>
                                            </option>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fondo del Evento</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="color" name="color" id="color">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start date</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">End date</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox" name="borrar_eventos"> Delete event</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_usuarios" id="id_usuarios">


                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

***Script para procesar ajax***

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end) {

                    $('#ModalAgregar #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalAgregar #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#ModalAgregar').modal('show');
                },
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                        $('#ModalEditar #id').val(event.id);
                        $('#ModalEditar #id_usuarios').val(event.id_usuarios);
                        $('#ModalEditar #title').val(event.title);
                        $('#ModalEditar #color').val(event.color);
                        $('#ModalEditar #description').val(event.description);
                        $('#ModalEditar').modal('show');
                    });
                },
                eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

                    edit(event);

                },
                eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                    edit(event);

                },
                events: [
                    <?php foreach ($events as $event) :

                        $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                        $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                        if ($start[1] == '00:00:00') {
                            $start = $start[0];
                        } else {
                            $start = $event['start'];
                        }
                        if ($end[1] == '00:00:00') {
                            $end = $end[0];
                        } else {
                            $end = $event['end'];
                        }
                    ?> {
                            id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                            id_usuarios: '<?php echo $event['id_usuarios']; ?>',
                            title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                            start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                            end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                            color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                            description: '<?php echo $event['description']; ?>'
                        },
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                ]
            });

            function edit(event) {
                start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                if (event.end) {
                    end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                } else {
                    end = start;
                }

                id = event.id;
                id_usuarios = event.id_usuarios;

                Event = [];
                Event[0] = id;
                Event[1] = start;
                Event[2] = end;
                Event[3] = id_usuarios;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'editarEventosFecha.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        Event: Event
                    },
                    success: function(rep) {
                        if (rep == 'OK') {
                            alert('Algo ha fallado !!');
                        } else {
                            alert('Se ha guardado !!');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    </script>
```

***editarEvento.php***

```
if (isset($_POST['borrar_eventos']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
    
    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM eventos WHERE id = $id";
    $query = $bd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bd->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al borrar el evento.');
    }
    $res = $query->execute();
    if ($res == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al borrar el evento.');
    }
```

***editarEventosFecha.php***

```
}elseif (isset($_POST['id_usuarios']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['color']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
        
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $id_usuarios = $_POST['id_usuarios'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    
        $sql = "UPDATE eventos SET id_usuarios = '$id_usuarios',  title = '$title', color = '$color' , description = '$description'  WHERE id = $id ";
    
        
        $query = $bd->prepare( $sql );
        if ($query == false) {
         print_r($bd->errorInfo());
         die ('Error al actualizar los datos del evento.');
        }
        $sth = $query->execute();
        if ($sth == false) {
         print_r($query->errorInfo());
        var_dump($query);
         die ('Error al actualizar los datos del evento.');
        }
    
    }


if (isset($_POST['Event'][0]) && isset($_POST['Event'][1]) && isset($_POST['Event'][2]) && isset($_POST['Event'][3])){
    $id = $_POST['Event'][0];
    $start = $_POST['Event'][1];
    $end = $_POST['Event'][2];
    $id_usuarios = $_POST['Event'][3];

    $sql = "UPDATE eventos SET id_usuarios = '$id_usuarios',  start = '$start', end = '$end' WHERE id = $id ";

    
    $query = $bd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bd->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al modificar la fecha');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al modificar la fecha');
    }else{
        die ('OK');
    }

}
```

Depuración

```
array(7) { ["title"]=> string(25) "Haaa fuera de horarioaaaa" ["id_usuarios"]=> string(1) "1" ["color"]=> string(7) "#400040" ["start"]=> string(19) "2021-11-08 19:30:00" ["end"]=> string(19) "2021-11-08 19:30:00" ["description"]=> string(3) "xxx" ["id"]=> string(2) "11" }
```

Como se puede observar no actualiza la hora en el mismo formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si arrastro con el cursor de un sitio a otro si que actualiza la fecha pero, si digo de actualizar con el input la hora no hace ningún cambio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estamos hablando de un problema de horas... ¿qué significa *pero este no me actualiza ni a la de tres*? ¿? ¿Qué ocurre con la columna implicada, se quedan en `NULL` o qué ocurre? ¿De qué tipo de dato es esa columna? ¿Hiciste **depuraciones de tus variables**? ¿Qué muestran? ¿Hay errores? ¿Qué errores?

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, esta expresión -> ¿qué significa pero este no me actualiza ni a la de tres? , quiere decir que no le encuentro el fallo ni depurando el por que no actualiza te pego las tablas de la aplicación arriba un saludo. !

Comment: Ya, pero no nos dices nada sobre el funcionamiento del código. ¿Muestra algún error? Y, empieza depurando los datos. Por ejemplo, pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. Y si hay errores dinos qué errores hay.

Comment: En seguida te lo muestro !

Comment: A ver, el `UPDATE` de las horas ocurriría si se cumple esto: `if (isset($_POST['Event'][0]) && isset($_POST['Event'][1]) && isset($_POST['Event'][2]) && isset($_POST['Event'][3])){`  PEEEERO según el `var_dump`  esa condición no se cumple, por tanto, ese UPDATE no va a ocurrir. Revisa en JS cómo estás pasando los datos al servidor, esa forma extraña de crear un array en la variable `Event` ¿qué pretendes con eso (me refiero a Javascript)? Pon un `console.log(Event);` antes de la petición Ajax y revisa la consola. En fin... **depura** tu código y revisa lo que estás mandando.

Comment: Si te fijas en el código, en el foreach le está pasando el formato de hora y luego la consulta ajax. pero como tu bien dices nunca manda la acción a ese archivo, y no llega, por lo cual no se actualiza, como podría hacerlo para que coja bien los datos ?

Comment: No entiendo el comentario... Si analizas la lógica de tu código y vas depurando podrás saber lo que está fallando. Comprende que para otro usuario puede resultar a veces difícil meterse en la lógica de un código a tientas, tratando de adivinar. Te digo esto porque estamos ante un caso típico en el cual: 1. Depurando y 2. Siguiendo paso a paso la lógica del código, encuentras el problema. Si haces eso te vas a ahorrar horas y hasta días y semanas programando. Depurar, depurar, depurar todo lo que falle, esa es la clave. Ya verificaste que ciertos datos no llegan en el POST ahora depura en JS.

Comment: Ya te dije que pongas un `console.log(Event);` en Javascript y que revises la consola. Así sabrás si el código llega a ese punto, y si llega, qué hay en `Event` y te darás cuenta por qué al `$_POST`  no llega nada con una clave llamada `Event`. Y quizá veas más errores en la consola (del navegador). O sea, todos estos son pasos básicos de depuración que deben hacerse en cualquier código que estés escribiendo.

Comment: Podrías indicarme porfa en que línea debo depurar para aprender mejor ? gracias!

Comment: Vale como dije a la hora de arrastrar el objeto si lo crea y lo hace bien es a la hora de pasarle la consulta ajax mira A.Cedano.

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar menos mal ! era tan simple como ponerlo en el editarEventos.php pasando por post las variables de start end !

Answer (score 0):

Para sorpresa mia lo he solucionado con pasarle las variables en post, precisamente no se las estaba pasando en el archivo editarEvento.php asique hice lo siguiente !

```
require_once('../back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php');

// var_dump($_POST);


if (isset($_POST['borrar_eventos']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
    
    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM eventos WHERE id = $id";
    $query = $bd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bd->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al borrar el evento.');
    }
    $res = $query->execute();
    if ($res == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al borrar el evento.');
    }
    
}elseif (isset($_POST['id_usuarios']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end']) && isset($_POST['color']) && isset($_POST['description'])  && isset($_POST['id'])){
    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id_usuarios = $_POST['id_usuarios'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];

    $sql = "UPDATE eventos SET id_usuarios = '$id_usuarios',  title = '$title',start = '$start',end = '$end', color = '$color' , description = '$description'  WHERE id = $id ";

    
    $query = $bd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bd->errorInfo());
     die ('Error al actualizar los datos del evento.');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
    var_dump($query);
     die ('Error al actualizar los datos del evento.');
    }

}
header('Location: eventos.php');
```

La consulta ajax lo que hace es crear el objeto, una vez que se arrastra de un dia a otro o incluso a un mes ! lo que aprende uno por estos lugares !
Y va perfectamente gracias por los consejos de depuración A.Cedano un saludo !